# Custom attribute returning null

Tags: android, android-xml

I made a library that i want to include in my project.

In that, i have this in my attr.xml:

```
 <declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
    <attr name="MyPrivateID" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

I included the library in my app, and it works fine. But i cant retreive my custom attribute.

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
...........>

<something.myown.MyCustomView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
custom:MyPrivateID="GjM4X9QfK2VT05BKlEyffkAKGLU=dhbdsljhbdDjTchvNTQwMg=="/>
```

And in MyCustomView.java, i have:

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyCustomView);
try {
    String string = a.getString(R.styleable.MyCustomView_MyPrivateID);
    return string;
} finally {
    a.recycle();
}
```

Somehow, string returns as null. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Are you able to change?

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.HalalAdView);
```

to

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyCustomView);
```

**EDITED**

Take a look in this sample. It's working https://github.com/betorcs/SampleCustomView

Comment: Are you trying to get `MyPrivateID` value in constructor?

Comment: Yes? Would that be a problem?

Comment: I edited answer, i created a sample for you. Take a look and try figure out what's different.

Comment: Thank you. got it working. It was because i had moved it out of my constructor. Even though I made sure that the constructor was called first! it seems like a bug.